# SPSS Python cases strings

Tags: python, spss

```
BEGIN PROGRAM PYTHON.
import spss
spss.StartDataStep()
frames=spss.Dataset(name="Frps")
datum=spss.Dataset(name="Datum")
for rowDat in range(len(datum.cases)):
    for rowFra in range(len(frames.cases)):
        fps = frames.cases[rowFra,1]
        if(fps[0] != '???'):
            datum.cases[rowDat,10] = float(fps[0])
spss.EndDataStep()
END PROGRAM.
```

I'm having trouble getting my code to ignore instances of `???` in my data. `if(fps[0] != '???'):` doesn't seem to be working. There must be something in the way in which cases stores strings that I'm not understanding.

Okay I figured it out if anyone has this same problem you can just put `if '???' not in str(fps[0]):`.